# Static Method call from unknown object

Tags: php

I want to call a static method from one of my objects. This is no problem if I know the name of the object, but in this case, I don't.
I have an array with several object names and I want to call the method from one of this arrays elements. So, it looks something like this:

```
function call_method($key)  {
    $tmp = array('key1' => 'objectname1','key2' => 'objectname2','key3' => 'objectname3');
    if(array_key_exists($key, $tmp))    {
        $tmp::static_method();
    }
}
```

But, this solution is not working. Does somebody know how to get this working?

Comment: "Not working" is a very broad problem.  Do you get an error?  Is it fatal?  What is it?  Do you not get what you expect?  If not, what do you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$tmp` is an array, so it has no static methods associated with it. You need to look up the value and use that:

```
// this will work for newer versions of PHP
$klass = $tmp[$key];
$klass::static_method();

// in some older versions, you may need to use call_user_func:
call_user_func(array($klass, 'static_method') /*, your args here */);
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I had to use the call_user_func(...). Now it is working. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Right now, you are trying to call the static function on that array. You should do :

```
 if(array_key_exists($key, $tmp))    {
    $tmp[$key]::static_method();
}
```

Thought you specified the names "object" in the array, I am assuming they are class names. Static functions cannot be called with instances.